# Using CompilerMessageAttribute to produce a compiler error, but only in other assemblies

Tags: f#

I have a union type that has a single, empty case.

```
type Default =
    | Default
```

This type has a purpose, but it's not meant to be visible or usable.
Unfortunately, I have to use it in an inline function that does need to be visible. This prevents me from making the type or the case private.

The solution I came up with is using the `CompilerMessageAttribute` on it to signal an error whenever it's used. This would be fine, but now I can't compile my own assembly because IT uses it.

Is there a way to signal an error only when it's used by an assembly that references my assembly?

Comment: Would `ObsoleteAttribute` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) serve the purpose?

Comment: @bytebuster Well, as far as I can tell it's objectively inferior to `CompilerMessageAttribute` for my use case. I can also just emit a warning instead of an error, but I really want an error. Other than that, `Default` isn't obsolete so it makes less sense semantically.

Comment: While I get that it's not meant to be visible, what happens if it is? Would it hurt?

Comment: As much as any other private element being visible I guess. Not that much, but there's absolutely no situation where user code should touch it.

Comment: Also, while I understand that it 'has a purpose', in my experience, whenever I get into situations like this, it eventually turns out that it was a design smell, and that there's a better alternative that doesn't require such stunts.

Comment: @MarkSeemann A valid concern, but in this case the hack is intentional and necessary (unfortunately).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me reiterate the requirements to make sure I understand them:

- The type needs to be *public*, so that that other assemblies can reference it *implicitly* via inline.
- But if other assemblies reference it *explicitly*, then that is an error.

I don't know of any way of doing this using standard tooling.

I can see two possible solutions.

If only *one* calling assembly needs to use the inline function, what about making the type internal and then have the calling assembly be a friend assembly, using the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

The only other alternative I can think of is security by obscurity. Hide the type in some awkwardly named module and require module qualification. This will stop accidental use of the type, if nothing else.
You could even add a build step to check that no source code references the module name.

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccessAttribute>]
module ``Dont Use This`` = 
    type Default =
        | Default

let x = ``Dont Use This``.Default
```

And yes, it's very kludgy.

Comment: I guess there are no better solutions.